# Computing the plane curves with given curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature

I want to compute the plane curves with curvature:

$\kappa (s) = 5/(s+1)$

I know I must apply the fundamental theorem of curves and solve some differential equation, but I am a bit confused about how to apply that theorem. Could you help with what equation must I solve and why?

Comment: Write down the Frenet equations to solve for $T(s),N(s)$ as a system of ODE. Then how do you recover the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polar angle $\theta$ of a tangent vector. You can see that $\theta'(s) = \kappa(s)$. Thus you can solve ODE:

$$
\theta'(s) = \frac 5{s+1},\qquad\theta(0)=\theta_0,\\
\theta(s) = \theta_0 + 5\ln (s+1).
$$

Then you can use the fact that tangent vector $(dx,\ dy) = (ds\cos\theta,\ ds\sin\theta)$. In other words, you have a system of independent equations:

$$
x'(s) = \cos\Big(\theta_0+5\ln(s+1)\Big),\qquad x(0)=x_0,\\
y'(s) = \sin\Big(\theta_0+5\ln(s+1)\Big),\qquad y(0)=y_0,
$$

For brevity, I will use $\theta_0=0$, but it doesn't make the integral any harder:

$$
x(s) = \frac{s+1}{26}\Big(\cos \theta(s) + 5 \sin \theta(s)  \Big)-\frac{1}{26} + x_0,\\
y(s) = \frac{s+1}{26}\Big(\sin \theta(s) - 5 \cos \theta(s) \Big)+\frac{5}{26} + y_0
$$

You have 3 degrees of freedom here: 2 for the location of a starting point $x_0,y_0$ and 1 for the arbitrary rotation of the curve $\theta_0$.